# Using triac as a tripping device

Tags: triac

Can i use DC Voltage (5DCV or more?) to trip the Gate of a Triac BTA series Transistor to connect Terminal 1 and Terminal 2 completing the circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need a resistor in series with the gate to limit the current. Read the data sheet to find the gate voltage at the desired trigger current. Make sure to give it enough current for all the applicable quadrants and for low temperature and worst-case sensitivity. Usually negative current is better, or necessary in cases where quadrant III operation (positive gate current, negative MT2 bias) is not guaranteed.

That will turn the triac on. It will not shut off until current drops to below the holding current and the gate current is removed.

Comment: Hi! , sorry my question is insufficient. What i meant to complete is  an AC circuit 220VAC 3A. So can i still use DCV(5V 750mA) to trip the Gate?

Comment: The answer above applies. The resistor value will depend on the triac specifications. Note that there is no isolation from the mains to the 5V- in many cases this is an unacceptable situation because of safety concerns.